# How to create code to translate sentence using my own dictionary. Without use google API

Tags: python, anaconda, translation

I have a problem how to do code about doing a translation from Jawi-Malay. I already have a dictionary/vocabulary dataset. I don't want to use Google API. Here is what I already do. I create a dataset to differentiate between two similar words as well known as homograph.

```
import nltk
import translate
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
from py_translator import TEXTLIB
from translate import Translator

biru = [
     ('A', 'باجو ساي بيرو'), 
     ('A', 'كتيك هاري ترڠ لاڠيت بيرو'),
     ('A', 'ورنا لاوت بيرو'),
 ]

biro = [
     ('B', 'فراس يڠ بتول اهلي بيرو دان اهلي لجنة'),
     ('B', 'بيرو ترجمهن نڬارا ڤرلو دتوبوهكن سڬرا'),
     ('B', 'بيرو دان لجنة ملقساناكن فوڠسي سڤرتي سبواه جاوتنكواس'),
 ]
```

Comment: Could you provide one or two samples of your expected output?

Comment: test_sentence = "بيرو ايت ڤرلو منجالنكن توڬس دڠن باءيق"
test_sentence = "باجو ساي بيرو"

print ("test_sent:",test_sentence)

Comment: #the output should be like this:

biro itu perlu menjalankan tugas dengan baik.
baju saya biru.

Comment: As you can see the words بيرو in Jawi either can be translated as a biru or biro in malay. 

I want to create the code that can differentiate that words when translated